# How to combine parts of two record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this T-SQL query here:

```
SELECT
    POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.id 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.merchantID 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.name 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.LegalName 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantContactDetails.EmailAddress 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.MCCRecord 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.addressLine1 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.addressLine2 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.addressLine3 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.addressLine4 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.city 
    , POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.phoneNumber 
FROM   
    POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails 
INNER JOIN
    POSH5_Prod_MerchantContactDetails ON POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.id = POSH5_Prod_MerchantContactDetails.MerchantRecord 
WHERE 
    POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.coreBankingRecord = 27 
    AND POSH5_Prod_MerchantDetails.active = 1
```

There are times where there will be two records with the same `merchantID`. What I would like to do is if that were to occur to take the `EmailAddress` column from one record and tack it onto the other record as `SecondaryEmailAddress` within the query result. Is there a way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to pivot your data.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar to (query reduced for brevity):

```
select MerchantRecord, [1] as EmailAddress, [2] as SecondaryEmailAddress 
from 
(
  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by merchantrecord order by EmailAddress) seq
  from POSH5_Prod_MerchantContactDetails 
) details
PIVOT(max(EmailAddress) FOR seq IN ([1],[2])) as pt
```